# Questions about the specifics of choir dress of ICKSP canons

Tags: canon, vestments

For some time now, I've been profoundly interested in the idiosyncracies of Catholic priest dress - particularly everyday (formal) and choir dress. Due to its uniqueness, in particular the dress of the Institute of Christ the King Sovereign Priest canons has piqued my interest.

It is my understanding that the formal dress entails a black cassock with blue buttons and trimming + pellegrina, with a blue fascia for ALL the priests, superiors and the general (no zucchetto or pectoral though, as that would make them look too much like bishops or cardinals). Or is it just the general, and the lower-ranking canons wear theirs with no pellegrina, or completely black? Or perhaps, is the privilege of wearing hte blue-buttoned cassock in everyday situations tied to Monsignor status, such as Chaplain of His Holiness, which the Prior General happens to hold?

Regarding the choir dress - it is said that it consists of a cassock, rochet, manteletta and mozzetta + biretta & distinctory. However, most available images (both photos and illustrations) also seem to include a second cape of sorts that encompasses the priest's figure even more widely and seems to be worn right under the mozzetta.

[image: The scheme of the ICKSP canon choir dress, from the left: priest, superior and prior general]

While the Prior General is demonstrated to wear this part in full blue in the schematic, Gilles Wach seems to wear it black, in this photo for instance:

[image: Gilles Wach, Prior General of the ICKSP]

This cape of sorts is not described anywhere (I can't find it at least). So my question is: is this part a ferraiulo? It seems to be a completely separate layer from the manteletta, which is directly below it.

Whether it is indeed a ferraiulo or not, then it would seem that these canons' choir dress is the most extensive and elaborate out of all Catholic clergy, combining the manteletta with the mozzetta, and even throwing in this extra cape for good measure. But I would like to be sure what exactly it is. Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not a ferraiulo. Why do you think it isn't a manteletta?

Comment: Because there is a part of it that's black, and part that's blue. 

I've actually done some more research, and turns out it's actually a mantellone - a longer version of the mantelletta that happens to reach the floor. It used to be worn in plain purple until 1969 by "prelates of the mantellone", who ranked lower than "prelates of the mantelletta". The blue and black parts being separate is just an illusion - in fact it's a single garment, the blue parts are just "wings" that fold outward, which are blue. The Prior General's manetllone is all blue (he's been seen to wear it on occasion).

Comment: Mantellones are not worn under mozzettas nor over rochets/surplices; plus only ever existed in purple.

Comment: Well in that case it must be a modified mantelletta that has the length of a mantellone. For all intents and purposes it's identical, except the color

Comment: It would be particularly strange for a traditionalist group to pattern their choir dress in contradiction to traditional norms, but I haven't seen a real photo which shows the length of the vestment

Comment: A mantelletta only reaches down to the length of the surplice-rochet, while theirs reach all the way down to the rim of the cassock. I've seen plenty of photos where that's plenty evident. Which makes me really wonder whether they're bringing back a sleeveless mantellone or just modifying the manteletta to be longer

Comment: Except a mantellone was never worn with a surplice/rochet nor under a mozzetta. While it's likely a traditionally minded group might look to more traditional style choir dress, they are unlikely to contradict so blatantly how things went together traditionally

Comment: And yet they do, or at least it seems that way. Still, mantellones I think had sleeves folded on the back (like wings), and there is no way to tell here, because they're covered up by the mozzetta. Then again, there's also the soprana - maybe they're actually wearing those? Sopranas were very similar to mantellones in practice, weren't they?

Comment: Anyhow, you can see in this picture that what they're wearing definitely reaches the bottom of their cassocks: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D-rmpfrWwAAYeaD.jpg

In most of these canons, I've noticed that this mantle doesn't usually spread wide apart, which makes me think it has a button closure near the neck, like some mantellettas sold for example here: https://psgvestments.com/collections/mantelleta/products/mantelleta-with-button-closure

Still, the length itself is very reminescent of a mantellone/soprana, which is definitely an unorthodox design.

Comment: I was able to find a pic showing them from behind: 
https://scontent.fwaw7-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.18172-8/19944600_10155074899568705_3737472369310975341_o.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=cdbe9c&_nc_ohc=gx9soToyyUIAX-sKvhM&_nc_ht=scontent.fwaw7-1.fna&oh=00_AfCMQesT12OoRHUAq480s7XHowkR7SjHFtnnNKhMfMzkbw&oe=63F8ABD8

Looks like there are no stripes of material hanging on the back sides of these mantles, so they can be neither mantellones nor sopranas. I wonder if they're separate vestments, or actually fastened to the mozzettas. In any case, it seems like just a longer mantelletta

Comment: Occam's Razor suggests the less assumptions is more likely. It's fewer assumptions that they are using a traditional vestment combined correctly but it's detailing has altered a bit then that they are using a traditional thing entirely out of its context